# How to create string contains HTML element in action method in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Action method:

```
 public ActionResult test()
 {
        ViewBag.aa = "hello <b>ali</b>";
        return View();
 }
```

View:

```
 @ViewBag.aa
```

Output:

```
hello <b>ali</b>
```

But I want ali in bold like following:

hello  **ali**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@Html.Raw(...`

```
 ViewBag.aa = "hello <b>ali</b>";
```

In view

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.aa)
```

For more check [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)